# Could geothermal energy extraction in Yellowstone significantly diminish the threat of a supervolcano?

Tags: geophysics, power, renewable-energy

I recently read an article about a team in Iceland that had managed to [drill directly into magma](http://theconversation.com/drilling-surprise-opens-door-to-volcano-powered-electricity-22515) coming up from the earth's mantle, and then use the resulting bore-hole to generate steam to power turbines.  This generated significant amounts of electricity, but would also presumably cool the magma slightly.

If we did this sort of energy extraction on a much larger scale in active hotspots, could it prevent volcanic eruptions, or at least significantly diminish their potential danger?  Might it possibly work as a prophylactic against a possible supervolcanic eruption in Yellowstone?

Comment: There are at least three questions here: 1) geothermal energy extraction, 2) volcanic hazard mitigation, and 3) super-volcanos. An answer to one of these alone would be difficult enough, and providing a sensible answer to a single case of all three may not be possible here. There is a lot of science and engineering efforts applied to each of the three individually - you might consider narrowing the scope of your questions. @mart's answer is valid, but I think one shouldn't take it to mean that the possibility of these ideas is somehow ruled out by physics.

Answer (score 3):

Ballpark estimate, I'm not a geoscientist so I don't kn ow if the whole idea even makes sense:

[This abstract of a paywalled articel](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/95GL00052/abstract) states  $4*10^{10} W$ Energy release and a mass flux of $3 * 10^4 kg s^{-1}$. So we are talking roundabout $1.3*10^6 J kg^{-1}$. A supervolcano eruption is [typically defined as yielding more than $450 km^3$ magma](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/364/1845/2073.full). Assuming a density 10 kg/l of magma, we have a lower bound for the energy budget of a supervolcano of $5.85*10^{15}J$. You would have to make an appreciable dent into this energy budget.

The civilized [world use of energy in 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_energy_consumption) was 474 Exajoules or $4.74*10^{20}J$. So we'd need 'just' steam turbines equivalent a millionth of humanities power budget to make a dent into the supervolcano. Writing the environmental impact statement for releasing this power into the environment as low grade heat might prove challenging.

Comment: My suspicion is that IRL  (in real life) releasing the pressure is the main problem.  A massive hot lava flow would just ruin a few vacationers' weekend :-), but if we could avoid a major explosion w/ resultant ash distribution, most of the impending disaster would be avoided.